# How to make a download button godot

Tags: download, path, godot

i've been working on a game in godot using gdscript. In this game I will need to download a txt file onto a user's computer at a click of a button so it can keep track of score. but when I make a file download it downloads into the source code what path should I make it.
code:

```
func _on_save_pressed():
   var file = File.new()
   file.open("save_data.txt", File.WRITE)
   file.store_string(score)
   file.close()
```

I have tried using /desktop and I would like this path to work for mac and windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `file.open("user://save_data.txt", File.WRITE)`.

[Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/data_paths.html#user-path-persistent-data)

Comment: that would work for save data but not for what i'm doing. It downloads it into a  file that is in the code that is used for saving data. I want to download it onto the computer like any file would from chrome onto the desktop or downloads file.

Comment: So you want to save the file to the downloads folder? If so, why? Also downloading is when you retrieve a file from the internet, if you're just saving a save file that's not called downloading.

Comment: Yes I am trying to save it to the downloads folder because That way you can share your score and because when I update the game it won't be saved under the app because they will have downloaded a new app so they will have to lose all of there progress.

Comment: Sorry for the bad grammer in that comment.

Comment: A player won't lose their progress once they update unless you rename your game.

Comment: Well I might rename it and also that allows me to edit already made settings. Also it could be used for opening save data from friends to view their progress. $Label.text+"\n"+str(cps)+"\n"+str(cpscps)+"\n"+str(cpc) is what im actually saving in the file in case that changes somthing.

Comment: I think a better solution would be a button that opens the user save folder. If you really want the downloads folder you can get it like `OS.get_environment("USERPROFILE").plus_file("Downloads/")`. I think you can also do something like `OS.get_environment("HOME").plus_file("Downloads/")` for Linux & MacOS, but I don't have a mac/linux computer so I don't know if that works.